# Django get max field value across filtered group of model instances

Tags: django

I need some help creating a custom Django query in my View.  I have two models, Department and Team, each Department can have multiple Teams.  A user can manually sort the Teams in any order and once done the order field is updated on each Team instance. So, now when a new Team is created I want to get the largest Team.order value within a specific Department.

This part below returns all of the Team instances `Team.objects.filter(department=team.department.id)`, but how do I then get the max value from the order field (other than looping)?

**VIEW**

```
class TeamCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = 'app/sidebar_team.html'

    # def get_initial(self):
    def get_initial(self):
        pk = self.request.GET.get('id')
        return {
            'department': pk,
        }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.author = request.user
            team.modified_date = timezone.now()

            # Get max Team.order value, increment by one, and set as new team.order
            max = Team.objects.filter(department=team.department.id).extra(Max('order'))

            team.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard/' + str(team.department.id))

        else:
            return redirect('/dashboard/' + str(form.department.id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "*fold*" the entire collection of items into one or more values, this is called an [**`.aggregate(..)`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset). So we can write an aggregate like:

```
Team.objects.filter(
    department=team.department.id
).aggregate(
    max_order=Max('order')
)['max_order']
```

The `.aggregate(..)` will perform a query, and return a dictionary with the result of the aggregates. Since here there is only one aggregate we do (with as name `max_order`), the dictionary thus contains that element. We can thus fetch it with the `['max_order']`.

Note that **in case there are no rows that match the filter** (or there are simply no  `Team`s at all), this will return a dictionary where with **as *value* `None`**. So then you will need to fix this. So for example if there are no `Team`s at all, then the `Team.objects.filter(..).agregate(..)` will return `{'max_order': None}`. It is then up to you to resolve that situation.

Comment: Perfect.  I found that while I was trying to figure this out but didn't have the right parameter inside the brackets for it work.  Thanks